# Android Studio : Too much indendation in code formatting

Tags: java, intellij-idea, android-studio

I've formatted the following code in Android studio:

```
mSignUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                     {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onClick(View v)
                                         {
                                             mValidator.validate();
                                         }
                                     }
    );
```

The indentation of the OnClickListener is very deep. After looking at the code formatting settings, I couldn't find a way to reduce it. Is there a way?

Comment: Select the block and hit Shift+Tab to unindent

Comment: @Der the IDE is lining up the implementation with the new statement. And that's exactly what he doesn't want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would indent it with IntelliJ.  This uses less lines.  This is using the default code formatting settings in IntelliJ

```
mSignUpButton.setOnClickListener( // Note: I put the new on the next line.
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mValidator.validate();
            }
        }
);
```

This would be in Java 8,

```
mSignUpButton.setOnClickListener(mValidator::validate);
```

Comment: @Rup good point, It does it automatically for you if you put the `new` on the next line.  It is still lining up with the `new` but this is far less indented to start with.

Comment: What is that Java8 syntax? (haven't done Java for a while). Can I get that using retrolambda?

Comment: Hmmm. tried the new on newline, and its still indenting like crazy, actually. Thought maybe it was related to my braces placement (next line), but no effect there. . .

Comment: @JasperBlues I am using IntelliJ CE with default code formatting. The android studio could be different....

Comment: It could be, but in any case by fiddling with line-breaks as suggested I found something that works. (I put it on a newline and it went crazy. Then I put it *back* on a single line up until the brace, and it formatted nicely).

Comment: @JasperBlues Are you using the formatter? i.e. ctrl+alt+L

Comment: yes, and via the useful keyboard shortcut. I rely on it whenever I used a Jetbrains IDE (IntelliJ, AppCode, Android Studio). Its a nice feature eh? Not sure why I got different results to you. Perhaps as I've customized the settings slightly.